# A simple threadpool in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17

Implemented a simple thread pool that executes task asyncly, and returns a simple future you can wait on. Can you please suggest improvements?

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdint>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>


class thread_pool {
public:
    using task_t = std::function<int()>;

private:
    struct pool_task {
        pool_task(task_t callable) : m_callable(std::move(callable)), m_task_value(0) {}

        void wait() {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_value_lock);
            m_value_cv.wait(lock, [this]() {
                return m_task_done.load();
            });
        }

        int value() {
            return m_task_value;
        }

        task_t m_callable;
        int m_task_value;
        std::mutex m_value_lock;
        std::condition_variable m_value_cv;
        std::atomic_bool m_task_done = false;
    };

public:
    /**
     *  Represents a future a client can use to receive
     *  the value returned from a submitted task.
     */
    struct future {
        future(std::shared_ptr<pool_task> task) : m_pool_task(task) {}

        int get() {
            m_pool_task->wait();
            return m_pool_task->value();
        }
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<pool_task> m_pool_task;
    };

    thread_pool(std::int32_t nthreads) : m_stopped(false) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++) {
            m_pool.emplace_back(std::thread([this]() {
                while (!m_stopped) {
                    execute_task();
                }
            }));
        }
    }

    thread_pool(const thread_pool& other) = default;
    thread_pool(thread_pool&& other) = default;

    ~thread_pool() {
        m_stopped = true;
        m_tasks_cv.notify_all();

        for (auto & thread : m_pool) {
            thread.join();
        }

    }

    future submit(task_t callable) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_tasks_lock);
        auto task = std::make_shared<pool_task>(callable);
        m_pool_tasks.emplace(task);

        return future(task);
    }

    /**
     * Stops all tasks.
     */
    void stop() {
        m_stopped = true;
        m_tasks_cv.notify_all();
    }

private:
    /**
     *  Execute a task fetched from the tasks queue.
     */
    void execute_task() {
        std::shared_ptr<pool_task> task = nullptr;
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_tasks_lock);
            m_tasks_cv.wait(lock, [this]() {
                return m_stopped || !m_pool_tasks.empty();
            });

            if (m_stopped) {
                return;
            }

            task = m_pool_tasks.front();
            m_pool_tasks.pop();
        }

        /**
         *  Shouldn't happen, but just in case..
         */
        if (task == nullptr) {
            return;
        }

        task->m_task_value = task->m_callable();
        task->m_task_done = true;
        task->m_value_cv.notify_one();
    }

    std::atomic_bool m_stopped = false;
    std::vector<std::thread> m_pool;
    std::queue<std::shared_ptr<pool_task>> m_pool_tasks;
    std::mutex m_tasks_lock;
    std::condition_variable m_tasks_cv;
};
```

Code works and tested, although not sure I've utilized C++17's full power.

Answer (score 1):

## Incorrect `#include`s

You have lots of unnecessary `#include` statements, for example `<atomic>`, `<cstdio>` and some others, but you are missing the required `<condition_variable>`.

## Make better use of the standard library

Why implement your own `class pool_task` and `class future` when the standard library already comes with [`std::packaged_task`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task) and [`std::future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future)? It could look like:

```
class thread_pool {
    …
    std::future<int> submit(std::function<int()> callable) {
        std::lock_guard lock(m_tasks_lock);
        m_pool_tasks.emplace(callable);
        return m_pool_tasks.back().get_future();
    }
    …
    void execute_task() {
        std::packaged_task<int()> task;
        {
            …
            task = std::move(m_pool_tasks.front());
            m_pool_tasks.pop();
        }
        task();
    }
    …
    std::queue<std::packaged_task<int()>> m_pool_tasks;
    …
};
```

## Don't mix atomics and mutexes

Make `m_stopped` a regular `bool` and only access it while holding `m_tasks_lock`. Otherwise, the problem is that `m_stopped` and `m_pool_tasks` are part of different synchronization scopes, and you will have subtle corner cases where things go wrong.

## Separate the queue from the thread pool

Your `class thread_pool` does several things: it implements a thread-safe queue for tasks, and it manages a pool of threads that take tasks from that queue. Consider splitting this up in two smaller, more maintable classes.

Comment: It seems like I did not the since C++11 part correctly. Sorry about that.

Comment: I dont think `std::packaged_tasks` will work here. When invoked it creates it own new thread. If I understand OP's intentions correctly he wants to reuse threads to remove thread creation overhead.  One can argue that `std::packaged_tasks` like `std::async` might use threadpools under the hood but the standard does not guarantee it.

Comment: @AjinkyaKamat `std::packaged_task` does not create a thread. It just wraps a callable so that its return value can be waited for and accessed in a thread-safe way.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Oh, so its like std::function but with std::future? That explains why my code is slow. Doh.